# What's the right way to reintegrate a branch intro trunk?

Tags: svn, merge, tortoisesvn

Im using the TSVN Gui on windows, and I've got a local copy of trunk.

I click merge and select the branch I want to merge with...

but I keep getting conflicts and neither the local or repository version of the files is right after resolving the conflicts...

this lead me to believe that Im merging this backwards.

So I tried to start with the branch and did the merge (reintegrate) and picked trunk from the repos.

Neither of these are working nicely.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should merge all changes from trunk to branch, before merging branch back to trunk.

Answer (score 2):

I've made a quick guide for this. You can check it out on coderwall - Subversion: Quick guide to create branches & reintegrate them without conflicts. - http://coderwall.com/p/ja06pg